# PPTX OpenXML - Which is the newline indicator in bulleted text?

Tags: powerpoint, openxml, presentationml

Can you please help me identify which is the newline indicator in bulleted text in 
PPTX OpenXML ? based on this I want add newline character in my program

-Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Break Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.drawing.break.aspx)

So for the following slide with bulleted list with a newline indicator:

[image]

Refer to the follwing code snipping showing from third bullet to fourth:

```
        using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation;
        using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
        using A = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing;
```

...

```
        A.Run run3 = new A.Run();
        A.RunProperties runProperties3 = new A.RunProperties(){ Language = "en-US", Dirty = false, SpellingError = true, SmartTagClean = false };
        A.Text text3 = new A.Text();
        text3.Text = "Th";

        run3.Append(runProperties3);
        run3.Append(text3);

        A.Run run4 = new A.Run();
        A.RunProperties runProperties4 = new A.RunProperties(){ Language = "en-US", Dirty = false, SmartTagClean = false };
        A.Text text4 = new A.Text();
        text4.Text = "";

        run4.Append(runProperties4);
        run4.Append(text4);

        A.Break break1 = new A.Break();
        A.RunProperties runProperties5 = new A.RunProperties(){ Language = "en-US", Dirty = false, SmartTagClean = false };

        break1.Append(runProperties5);

        A.Run run5 = new A.Run();
        A.RunProperties runProperties6 = new A.RunProperties(){ Language = "en-US", Dirty = false, SpellingError = true, SmartTagClean = false };
        A.Text text5 = new A.Text();
        text5.Text = "ird";

        run5.Append(runProperties6);
        run5.Append(text5);
        A.EndParagraphRunProperties endParagraphRunProperties1 = new A.EndParagraphRunProperties(){ Language = "en-US", Dirty = false, SmartTagClean = false };

        paragraph3.Append(paragraphProperties3);
        paragraph3.Append(run3);
        paragraph3.Append(run4);
        paragraph3.Append(break1);
        paragraph3.Append(run5);
        paragraph3.Append(endParagraphRunProperties1);
```

This code was generated with the [Open XML Productivity Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=5124).  I highly recommend you use it to reverse engineer the things you need to write code for in Excel, Word and PowerPoint.

Hope this helps...